# PHP - Why does file_get_contents() behave like this and how a I solve this newline issue?

Tags: php, behavior, file-get-contents

If I have this code:

```
$numbers = array_unique(explode(",", file_get_contents('text.txt')));

print_r($numbers);
```

With this text file:

```
hello,world,hello
```

Everything works as expected with the output:

```
Array ( [0] => hello [1] => world )
```

I encountered the following problem when changed the text file to this:

```
hello,
world,
hello
```

<sub>(Just in case, added newlines...)</sub>

Now, the output is:

```
Array ( [0] => hello [1] => world [2] => hello )
```

I can't fully understand why since ir seems to be *exploding* correctly but not applying the `array_unique()`. But that is just my trivial interpretation of the problem, I have no clue as to what is going on here.

I found some other unexpected behavior (unexpected to me at least):

With this text file:

```
hello,
hello,
hello,
hello,
world,
hello
```

I had this output:

```
Array ( [0] => hello [1] => hello [4] => world )
```

So, the questions:

- What is actually going on here?

  - Is it the same issue on both situations?
- How can I solve this? (without getting rid of the newlines(*preferably*)).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use var_dump instead of print_r and you should be able to see the new lines causing your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the following file:

```
hello,
world,
hello
```

PHP sees it as the following string:

```
hello,\nworld,\nhello
```

Therefore, when calling [`explode(',', $fileData)`](http://php.net/explode), PHP separates the array elements as follows:

```
[0] hello
[1] \nworld
[2] \nhello
```

Since all three elements are not unique, [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/array_unique) makes no changes.

Try to [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) all elements before running [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/array_unique) using [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map):

```
$elements = array_map('trim', $elements);
```

This will remove all whitespace before and after each element, which will result in the following array:

```
[0] hello
[1] world
[2] hello
```

Comment: +1 PHP seems to have a function for everything! :) Nice approach, I still don't understan this output `Array ( [0] => hello [4] => world )` with the second text file. Thanks!

Comment: @Trufa: What second file, and what code are you using for that output? If you mean the `Array ( [0] => hello [1] => hello [4] => world )` output, [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var_dump) would of shown you that your elements were `[0] => hello, [1] => \nhello, [4] => \nworld`.

Comment: @Andrew Moore @Trufa For the same reasons in Trufa's last example, \nhello duplicates are removed. So you get hello \nhello and \nworld unique entries.

Comment: @AndrewMoore: Sorry I was not clear enough I ment this `hello,
hello,
hello,
hello,
world,
hello` which outputs: `Array ( [0] => hello [1] => hello [4] => world )`I'm using `print_r($numbers);`and var_dump(), if that was what you were asking.

Comment: @Jacob: Should I get (I the case without new lines): `Array ( [0] => hello [1] => world )`? I get `Array ( [0] => hello [4] => world )`

Comment: @Trufa [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) preserves keys... "Note that keys are preserved" Because world was the 4 element in the array before the function was applied it retains its previous key.

Comment: @Trufa: If you want to re-index your keys, you can use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array_values).

Comment: @Jacob: Ah sorry ok, so it was behaving as expected, sorry for the newbie mistake!! Thanks you!

Comment: @AndrewMoore: Good to know, I was about to search fot that, thank you for your answer, very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Because first is **"Hello"** second is **"\nWorld"** third is **"\nHello"** and each is unique.
var_dump your array to see the difference.

try explode(",\n" ...

Comment: Hi, while this appears to be true I get this output: `Array ( [0] => hello [4] => world )` when I do so!

Comment: Do so? whats so!? use var_dump to debug ur output

Comment: @AbiusX: I did, It's not helping (me): `array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "hello" [4]=> string(5) "world" }`

Comment: Maybe I'm seriously wrong but I was expecting `Array ( [0] => hello [1] => world )`

Comment: @AbiusX: I'm sorry I did not know that array_unique preserved the keys, that got me confused, thanks! +1

Answer (score 0):

when you explode(",") it's only a comma.

As soon as you created new lines, it adds a \n to it (which is invisible because it does not display a character, but tells the file it's a new line).

You may want to look at file() instead which puts each line into it's own unique array element.

Comment: I imagined that might be the proble but had only tried `\r\n`The problem is (now) if I do `explode(",\n",file_get_contents('text.txt')` then I get this output: `Array ( [0] => hello [4] => world )`. Thanks!! BTW: I'm aware of the file() function but I wanted to experiment with this function.